# Do we need any init steps in this scenario?

Tags: 7, drush, installation, multi-sites

In Order to install Drupal Core using Code deploy, I follow these steps.

1. Download drupal-7.x.zip
2. /usr/bin/unzip -o /tmp/drupal.zip
   /bin/mv /var/www/drupal-7.x /var/www/drupal
3. Similar steps to download and unzip the modules / themes etc
4. Deployment of configuration under sites and restart apache

Do we need any Drush init steps in this scenario? How do we upgrade using Drush commands only?

Comment: What is code deploy?

Comment: AWS code deploy service - This service allows to script the deployment steps on the server.